# Assigning to result of np.maximum giving "Assigning to function call which doesn't return" linter error

Tags: python, numpy, pylint

I have a pandas dataframe `df` and I'm trying to make the following assignment

```
df["my.col"] = np.maximum(df["my.col"].fillna(0) / 10, 10)
```

Pylint comes with the error:

```
Assigning to function call which doesn't return (assignment-from-no-return)
```

Why is pylint complaining with what appears to be a false positive?

I tried `np.maximum` and the output is correct, but linter complains.

Answer (score 0):

Pylint may generate this warning because it is unable to reliably detect the return type since it is unaware of the unique behavior of numpy routines.

You can use a comment to show that you understand what you're doing and that this assignment is deliberate in order to suppress this particular pylint warning